# How to update the items of qCombox in custom form?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt

For my project I use a custom form with multiple value relation comboboxes.
This works quite fine and I can access the widgets via my script.

Init the two comboboxes which are correctly filled

```
cb_type = mydialog.findChild(QComboBox, "type")

cb_subtype = mydialog.findChild(QComboBox, "subtype")
```

Watch first one to change

```
cb_type.currentIndexChanged.connect(changeType)

function called when combobox1 is changed

def changeType():
    change filter of value relation of combobox 2 - works
    mylayer.valueRelation(2).mFilterExpression = "\"somefielname\"=\'some attribute\'"
```

HOW TO REFRESH THE VALUES HERE?

Now the problem is that the attributes are not updated until I close and reopen the form.
Mybe someone can help me to solve the problem, that the list is refreshed automatically!

Comment: As I forgot to say, it should work for 2.2 api